# The difference between $\sin(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ when it comes to integration

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I understand the similarities of a sine function and a hyperbolic sine function. They are both sums of natural exponential function but the difference is that one is complex and the other is real. In other words $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$$ and $$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$$

My question is if I was to find the anti derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$. Here is what I would do.

Let $x=\sin(t) \Rightarrow dx=\cos(t)\,dt$.
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}=\int\frac{\cos(t)dt}{\sqrt{1-\sin(t)^{2}}}$$
$$=\int{dt}=t=\sin^{-1}(x)$$

The assumption that $x=\sin(t)$ has created a solution as shown above. But if I were to start with a new assumption that $x=\sinh(t)$.  By following the same procedure that the solution to the anti derivative becomes $\sinh^{-1}(x)$. Now this shows that the two solutions are possible for the anti derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$. Now if we make this practical and look at a sag of transmission line, it follows a hyperbolic function derived from the above anti derivative. But if we started with a sine function we would have concluded that the sag of a transmission line is a sinusoid (which is not the case). So doesn't this create a contradiction.

Comment: It is the difference that equals 1 instead of the sum.

Comment: observe that $\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{(\cos x)^2}}=\frac{\cos x}{|\cos x|}\neq 1$

Comment: For $x$ real, both $\sinh(x)$,$\sin(x)$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong. The procedure that you applied in order to find an antiderivative of $\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is correct. But it doesn't work if you use $\sinh$ instead of $\sin$, because $1-\sinh^2\neq\cosh^2$. The similar equality that holds is $1+\sinh^2=\cosh^2$. And you *can* use it to find an antiderivative of $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.